# "ERROR: column rel.relhasoids does not exist" with PostgreSQL 12 and PgAdmin 4.3

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I get the following error when trying to select rows from a table:

```
ERROR:  column rel.relhasoids does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT rel.relhasoids AS has_oids
```

Configuration is:

- Linux RHL8
- NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
- VERSION="8.2 (Ootpa)"
- postgresql12-server-12.3
- psql (12.3)
- PgAdmin 4.3 en 4,5

Answer (score 4):

The column `relhasoids` has been dropped from the system catalog `pg_class` in PostgreSQL v12, because the long deprecated `WITH OIDS` clause has been removed from `CREATE TABLE`.

Obviously you are using an old version of pgAdmin 4 that has not got the message yet.

Upgrade to a newer version of pgAdmin, and the error should vanish.